# Сезон встречей / сезон встреч

Tags: орфография, множественное-число

Исходное предложение: «Продолжаем осенний сезон встречей в рамках выставки XXX».

Почему «встречей», а не «встреч»?

Результаты поисковой выдачи показывают, что «сезон встречей» также используется.

Неужели «встречей» – это тоже корректная форма в данном контексте?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разница в числе.

*Продолжаем осенний сезон (чем?) встречей с каким-то деятелем.* || Встреча только одна. Творительный падеж.

*Продолжаем осенний сезон (чего?) встреч.* || *Встречи* — множественное число. Родительный падеж.

При множественном числе в родительном падеже у данного слова не может быть окончания "ей":
[https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/встреча](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B0)

Comment: Спасибо! Теперь стало ясно. Здесь разница скорее сначала в падеже (тв./род.), а затем в числе (ед./мн.).

Comment: При множественном числе в родительном падеже не может быть окончания ЕЙ?  Эта как же так? Для сущ . второго и третьего склонения это обычное дело, и даже встречается среди сущ. первого склонения. СВЕЧА, -и; мн. свечи, свечей и свеч, свечам;ПРОСТЫНЯ, -и; мн. простыни, род. -тынь, -ней,

Comment: @Sharon Да я только про слово "встречи". И привожу ссылку, где все падежи этого слова.

Comment: Предложение сформулировано, точка поставлена, а утверждение  в нем неверное.  Будьте внимательны. (Ведь я могу и не смотреть на ссылку).

Answer (score 0):

Да, это корректная форма. Более того, она представляется здесь более естественной по ситуации. Но это сказать наверняка нельзя, не имея контекста.

У этих форм разные значения. Одна относится к слову "продолжать", а другая к "сезону".

"[продолжаем] встречей" отвечает на вопрос "чем?". Чем можно продолжить сезон? Походом в кино, прогулкой, встречей с одноклассниками.
А "[сезон] встреч" отвечает на вопрос "какой?": сезон прогулок, походов, встреч.

Как легко видеть, это совершенно разные и абсолютно не взаимозаменяемые конструкции. Вы, видимо, рассматриваете только вторую возможность, потеряв первую.

Да, как уже сказали, первое - творительный падеж единственного числа, а второе - родительный множественного, но это само по себе вряд ли что вам прояснит. Если у вас подобные затруднения, то важно понять всю грамматику, а не запомнить падежи.

Я ответил в предположении, что спрашивающий изучает русский как иностранный. Человеку с родным русским разница должна быть очевидна. Извините, если ошибаюсь.

Comment: *Человеку с родным русским разница должна быть очевидна.* И всё же автор может быть и русским и не сообразить, что тут такой смысл: зациклился именно на сезоне каком. Если есть продолжение "встречей с кем-то", тогда согласен: сложно не понять.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой ну не знаю. Это ж до какой степени надо уйти в себя... Он же в интернете примеры искал - и все равно не понял. Хотя после комментария под принятым ответом можно поверить во что угодно.  )))

Comment: А что не так с тем комментарием? Людям нужен конкретный чёткий ответ без воды. Растягивать есть смысл ответы на "почему".

Comment: Где не так? У мене все так. Если человек лделает вид, что ему что-то стало понятнее подобного ответа, то это выглядит по меньшей мере странным.

Comment: У меня всё коротко и понятно. А в растянутых ответах велика вероятность запутаться или не уловить ключевые моменты.

Comment: @oleedd Зачем вы это пишете под моим ответом? Хвалите себя в другом месте, если не трудно.